# Numpy padding a 4D array is slow

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I'm trying to pad a 4D numpy array. This array is just a collection of 3D arrays, for example, its size can be interpreted as (samples, height, width, depth). The array size before padding is (1682160, 21, 200, 3). I would like to pad the rows in this array by 10 pixels in each side, hence my final padded array size would be (1682160, 21, 220, 3). I currently use the numpy pad function this way:

```
matrix = np.pad(matrix, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (10, 10), (0,0)), mode='reflect')
```

I rewrite the padded array `matrix` into the same variable since it is float16 datatype, with a size of roughly 40 GB. Writing into a new matrix results in a memory error. The execution time for the above command is roughly 700 seconds.

I would like to know if there is a faster way of implementing this in python, maybe in a vectorized fashion?

Comment: Will you be splitting this array into mini-batches at any point? Perhaps padding the mini-batches rather than doing the whole job all at once could help?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, it looks like the execution of the padding operation is non-linear in size. Breaking it down into two halves now results in an execution time of 250 seconds total. 
Now, I have to figure out how to parallelize the next step (neural network fitting) for these two halves, because if I do it serially, it will take longer than padding the full matrix.